# Angular dynamic overlay component loading

Tags: angular, typescript

i have to create a component which works like an overlay (position: absolute etc.) and im wondering which way is correct.

I heard an advice that you can pass a flag, which decides if overlay is visible as @Input and render its content depending on value of this flag. The second way I know is creating component dynamically, using View Container in code behind. For me the second option sounds much better in terms of clean code, but obviously you have to create more typescript code then.

Maybe you have any other ideas? Thanks for your answer.

(I know it's been already done in material etc. but in this case i had to do this myself)

Comment: Would you be able to provide a little more information as it relates to your specific requirements? There are many, many ways to do this based on what you have stated and they all have various trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use Angular CDK not material by this you have control how you want
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aycsad?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In this case I had to do this myself